# About Google Calendar API and PHP

Tags: php, composer-php, google-calendar-api

I am trying to write a webpage that will present to the public the contents of one of my Google Calendars. The standard iframe doesn't give me the format I'd like and I also want to embed some schema.org event information, update and submit a sitemap, etc.

As I'm fairly experienced with PHP, I'm trying to extract data from the Google Calendar API. I looked at Google's quickstart  https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php but it assumes a level of knowledge I don't possess.

It seems I need to use something called "composer" and tells me I need to do "composer require google/apiclient:^2.0" but I'm unclear where exactly I type this - I can't see anywhere obvious in cPanel - or maybe it goes at the start of my PHP code?

Also, I note that the sample code is command-line only and I can't find code anywhere that would appear to be capable of running as a PHP web page. Is that because it's just not possible?

Comment: This is too broad of a question. You need to install `php-cli` for your OS (command line interface for php), then you need to install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) which is a package manager. Then in the folder of your project you can start building it (`composer require` needed package, create `index.php` file, require generated `autoload.php` file by `composer` in your PHP file and begin working with said package). Look up some basic `PHP` and `composer` guides for beginners - that will be a decent start for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I found "PHP Tutorial: Getting Started with Composer" and it told me:Installing composer

Linux & Mac:
curl -sS [https://getcomposer.org/installer](https://getcomposer.org/installer) | php 
I wasn't sure where to put this in cPanel but guessed that Terminal might be right and typed it there but I got "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('"
Should I be somewhere else in CPanel? Sorry to ask such basic questions. Thanks in advance

Comment: cPanel provides terminal access, so it might be good to go (ideally you would want to connect to your server via SSH to run the commands and set up the environment properly). Anyway you are better contacting your web hosting provider or reading documentation they provide (if they do) about deploying PHP apps and composer.

Comment: Thanks. They sent me links to documentation that told me I first needed to have something called Easy Apache. Then it suggested I might need to upgrade from version 3 to version 4 but it wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Composer is a dependency manager like bower, npm, yarn etc., the list goes on and on. Firstly you'll have to install composer [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/) and add it to your PATH variable (method depends on OS).

Afterwards, when you create a directory for your project in the www-folder of your WAMP/LAMP or another folder acting as webroot, you can execute the composer require command. This will generate a folder called 'vendor' (with your dependency as a subdirectory) and a composer.json & composer.lock file, the latter 2 files will contain all the 'required dependencies' of composer.

You can then include the dependency using the require_once()-function in your PHP-script.

Hopefully this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've managed to install composer but I can't see a way to do PATH from cPanel. Also I can't see WAMP or LAMP?

Comment: I think I'm barking up the wrong tree here. A couple of years ago, I used the Google Maps API for a really complex project and I just wrote the code, used FTP to put it in place and didn't have to do anything with the lower levels of an OS which I don't understand. 
Is it just not possible to write a dozen lines of PHP which will read a publicly accessible Google Calendar
I've found out that Google supports CalDAV and am looking to see if that's simpler
Thanks